# Assign different build types to different Flavors in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

In my Gradle file, I've assigned `buildTypes` and `productFlavors` in the following way.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    release{
        //storeFile file("")
        //storePassword ""
        //keyAlias ""
        //keyPassword ""
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    dev{
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.xxx.android.dev"
    }
    qa{
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.xxx.android.qa"
    }
    staging{
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.xxx.android.staging"
    }
    prod{
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.xxx.android.prod"
    }
}
```

Now the problem is each flavors has the both build types which is release and debug , But I want to assign debug for build only so we cannot produce a release build when selecting debug variant. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please elaborate.
You don't want release build or you don't want anything to happen when realease build is selected?

Comment: Well i managed to get it done by adding build targets. i  didn't want to change any source codes for this . so no nee to go with flavors

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done by adding build targets. i didn't want to change any source codes for this . so no need to go with flavors

```
buildTypes {
        qa {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', ‘BASE_URL', ‘"url“'

    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         buildConfigField 'String', ‘BASE_URL', ‘"url“'

    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField 'String', ‘BASE_URL', ‘"url“'
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you put `buildConfigField` elsewhere since it's the same for all three?  And what is the point of release and qa if they're the same?